# How did Logan know what the green serum was?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

In the movie *Logan*, the kids show him that they have a bottle of the green serum from Transigen that they use on X-24. They tell him that it speeds up his healing for a short time. Logan then says something like: "It will do more than that, this stuff will make you crazy".

How could Logan possibly know that?  It seems implied that he knows exactly what it is, but it seems extremely unlikely that Transigen would just let any old remaining mutants have it.

Comment: He must have encountered it sometime in his long lived past.

Comment: It's also possible he read about it in the Transigen files in Laura's backpack.

Comment: Either that or he knows it's something that Transigen produced and is naturally wary of it, as Transigen is basically the modern equivalent of the Weapon X Program